Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ of smooth functions $f\in C^l$ decays fast.
I want to prove the above statement, which motivates why the Fourier transform on the Schwartz space is automorphic.
Let $f\in C^l(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\alpha$ a multiindex of at most order $l$. From the definition of the Fourier transform we know
$$\mathcal{F}[D^\alpha f] =(ik)^{|\alpha|} \mathcal{F}[f]$$
So we get
\begin{align}
\tilde f(k):=\mathcal{F}[f] 
&= (ik)^{-|\alpha|} \mathcal{F}[D^\alpha f]\\
&= (ik)^{-|\alpha|} (2\pi)^{-d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} D^\alpha f e^{-ik\cdot x}dx \\
&\leq (ik)^{-l} (2\pi)^{-d} \Vert D^\alpha f e^{-ik\cdot x}\Vert_\infty
\end{align}
Now devide the term $(ik)^{-l}$ to the other side:
$$\tilde f(k)(ik)^l \leq \Vert D^\alpha f e^{-ik\cdot x}\Vert_\infty \to 0,\text{ for }k\to \infty$$
Conclusion: for every polynomial of order $l$, denoted as $p_l(k)$, we have
$$\tilde f(k) \cdot p_l(k) \to 0,\text{ for }k\to \infty, $$
So that $\tilde f$ decays faster than any polynomial of order $l$?
Is this proof correct?
The reverse ("fast decaying function has smooth Fourier transform") is then straight forward.

For $FD_jf = ik_jFf$ you need $f$ to vanish at $\infty$ to justify the integration by parts.

I see. However then I can not show that smoothness alone implies decay of Fourier trafo, right?
